# Could not import tensorflow on python 3.7.6 on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have recently uninstalled Anaconda and Python because I unintentionally uninstalled h5py.

But everything seemed to stop working ever since.

Now after re-installing Anaconda with Python 3.7.6, I tried installing TensorFlow again, which is installed properly.

The issue happened when I tried to import it. The error as follows:

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     48 import numpy as np
     49 
---> 50 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     51 
     52 # Protocol buffers

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     67 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     68 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 69   raise ImportError(msg)
     70 
     71 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Ive tried almost everything ive seen by changing tensorflow to 2.0 but it still didnt work. Any solution is highly appreciated!

EDIT:
Additional stuff that I tried:
- running pip install h5py

Comment: did you see this thread: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35749

Comment: Hi Anna, thanks so much for the link. I have had a read on it and tried the solution by downgrading my tensorflow to version 2.0 but when i tried to run it again i encountered the following problem that:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat'

Comment: what call are you using to downgrade to `tensorflow`? on python 3 you'll want to use `pip3`

Comment: Hi as what is written on one of the solution in the link I have used the comment !pip install tensorflow==2.0. Forgive me because I am quite new to this but would pip3 and pip be different ?

Comment: Typically, the `pip` call is a soft link to `pip3`... but if you are on Mac, `pip` calls the Mac pre-installed version of `Python 2.7`. I have a feeling either your link is messed up or you're on Mac

Comment: As of the moment I am using windows 10, sorry for not being clear enough, ill add this information to the main question

Comment: okay, that's good to know! could you do `pip which pip` in your terminal and tell me the output?

Comment: I've tried using the !pip which pip and it sadly didn't work. 

However, good news was one of the solutions in the link you provided me asked me to install a specific file and after restarting it worked for me!

Anyhow thanks again for the advice!

Comment: awesome! You should post that solution to this question and close it out!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

Ive downgraded my tensorflow to version 2.0 by:

`!pip install tensorflow==2.0`

then ive also download x64: vc_redist.x64.exe on the following link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads